# Merge MySQL Rows Together

Tags: mysql, merge, rows

I have a table laid out a bit like this:

```
ID  | Date       | Description          | Notes
 1  | 2015-03-25 | Action Completed     | 
 2  | 2015-02-12 | Action Not Completed |
 1  |            |                      | Completed With Ease
 2  |            |                      | Difficulty Performing
```

Is there any code that I can use to merge them together by ID, like this?

```
 ID | Date       | Description          | Notes
 1  | 2015-03-25 | Action Completed     | Completed With Ease
 2  | 2015-02-12 | Action Not Completed | Difficulty Performing
```

I have already looked, but couldn't find anything that worked properly.

Comment: Have you tried simply a NATURAL JOIN?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/305b7/1

```
SELECT id, 
  max(`date`),
  GROUP_CONCAT(Description),
  GROUP_CONCAT(Notes)
FROM table1
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: The same thing happens with both answers. It appears to work, but when I refresh my page everything reverts to how it was. What should I do?

Comment: @thatguythere what do you mean by refresh? show us your page and your code

Comment: When I refresh the page in the browser. I am using phpmyadmin.

Comment: you can not refresh phpmyadmin page to get query result - you have to press button **go** or **run** or **refresh** but it should be button or link on the page

Comment: I paste in the code in the SQL tab, then I click go and then it brings up the table. It all looks like it has been done but when I refresh the page, it just goes back to how it was.

Comment: you can not refresh the page! find the button or link on that page to refresh! **don't use refresh button of your browser or F5**

Answer (score 0):

Group by the column that should be unique an then use aggregate functions on the other columns like `max()`

```
select id, 
       max(date) as date, 
       max(description) as description, 
       max(notes) as notes
from your_table
group by id
```

Comment: This appears to work, but when I refresh my page everything reverts to how it was. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No idea. You can ask another question about that, providing code, language you use and so on.